# SignalR working on Localhost, BUT not working on Server win server 2019 with IIS

Tags: signalr, negotiate

I have project with SignalR + MVC, this not working on Server win server 2019 with IIS.
I Got errors:

```
signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B"name"%3A"feedbackhub"%7D%5D&_=1646730379815
```

[image]

Can anybody help me?

This all my Code:
https://github.com/duc14s/SignalRFeedbackSample

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled websockets on the server?

- On the taskbar, click Server Manager.
- In Server Manager, click the Manage menu, and then click Add Roles and Features.
- In the Add Roles and Features wizard, click Next. …
- On the Server Roles page, expand Web Server (IIS), expand Web Server, expand - Application Development, and then select WebSocket Protocol.

Comment: Thank you Hedgybeats, BUT WebSocket Protocol installed. I note that, I tested on asp.net core 5, this working. But i want to add this Existing my project MVC project. This strangely, i have found many solutions, maybe related to IIS... BUT this not working.

Comment: Thank you @Hedgybeats.  I done WebSocket Protocol in IIS. And if run with ASP.NET Core , this working. But it not working on Asp.net MVC and Asp.net webform. I tried many ways, but still can't fix this error